# Trying to cite in LaTeX using biblatex but won't create bibliography or insert citations

Tags: biblatex

I'm a new user and am trying to use biblatex to cite in LaTeX. Currently all my code is giving me is my citation put in to my text as my bibtexkey in brackets, or nothing at all. It is also not forming a bibliography. I build LaTeX-->PDF, followed by LaTeX--> bibtex , and then LaTeX-->PDF again. The .bib file has inserted and a .bbl file created. I'm using JabRef to manage my references. I don't understand where I am going wrong. Below is my minimal example.

```
\documentclass {report}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
    style=authoryear, 
    maxcitenames=2, 
    sorting=nyt,
    backref=true]{biblatex}

\bibliography{refs}

\let\cite\parencite

\begin{document}

Just to check referencing \citation{Bian2008}

\printbibliography

\enddocument
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You have `backend=biber` (which is default for `biblatex`), so you either have to run `biber` instead of `bibtex`, or switch to `backend=bibtex`. There are instructions for setting up various editors to run `biber` in [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/).

Comment: I now get this error: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\biber.exeCannot execute the command. Error: The requested operation requires elevation. I am the administrator on my laptop and have changed the preferences on biber to 'Run this program as an administrator' to no avail.

Comment: I don't know what causes that, I'm afraid. Does it work if you use `backend=bibtex` instead, and run `bibtex` as you tried earlier?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using bitex instead now, but it can't find 'bibtex.sty'?! I'm so confused by all this!

Comment: @Batch BibTeX isn't a `.sty` file, it's a separate program you run

Comment: Yes, I have run bibtex.exe but that is the error that then appears and stops compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
 \addbibresource{refs.bib}
```

(with the extension) instead of `\bibliography{refs}, and run Biber, as Torbjøn T. said.

Comment: While `\addbibresource` is recommended, `\bibliography` will work as well.

Comment: Then maybe it's a problem with the cache of biber (corrupted for some reason). If you're on Windows, I can help: biber create a directory in `C:\Users\<yourname>\AppData\Local\Temp` named | par-` + a lot of figures (seems to be an hexadecimal something). Just delete it and launch biber again.